# Footer (navbar) not being relative to the sidebar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am kinda new to webpage development. So, please bear with me. I made the footer of my site by using the navbar in Bootstrap 3.

I need the footer to stay at the bottom of the page, obviously. I have my grid system as 2 8 2. Now, the footer works perfectly for the mid grid, i.e., `col-8`. But fails miserably for the right column.

FOOTER:

```
<div class="footer navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-left"> Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer { 
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ccffcc;
    color: white; 
}

.container { 
    width: auto;
    max-width: 680px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Problematic scene:
 [Please look at the right side of the page. The footer's misbehavior with the sidebar....so to speak.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSOr5.jpg)

Comment: Could use a sticky footer. Take a look at the HTML and CSS of this (right click on your browser and view source and click on the CSS file in the HTML) https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Roy at least add the css  `html,body{height:100%; overflow:auto;}`

Comment: Someone please give me a solution, please keep in mind that I am using Bootstrap's navbar as the footer, and that it responds perfectly with the middle grid. I want the same to happen with the smaller grids on either sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [bootstrap sticky-footer](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) to have an example.

In your html/css you have to add :

CSS :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Your content.</p>
  <div class="push"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
   <p>Copyright</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for being so late guys. I resolved this a long time back, couldn't respond, sorry. Simply used min-width for the page.